# Should I accept an answer on a bountied question that breaks another part of the code?

Tags: discussion

I put a bounty on this question: [Gap between clipping regions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12825343/gap-between-clipping-regions) and I got an answer.

Problem: while technically the answer is correct, one important side-effect of the answer breaks something else.

Before: an antialiased polygon with a problem in the center.

Afer: a non-antialiased polygon with no problem in the center.

I can't accept the answer because, in my opinion, it causes more damage that it solves. But it's still an interesting answer and the actual answer can possibly be derived from it.

Comment: *[O]ne important side-effect of the answer breaks something else.* The only answer I can see suggests to disable anti-aliasing. That's hardly a side effect; it's the proposed solution.

Comment: You don't need to accept an answer to award a bounty.

Comment: I don't know anything about anti-aliasing, so I'm not even going to try looking at the original question. But I think the only factor to consider here is whether the asker gave the answerer enough information to know that the proposed solution would cause problems. If the initial code sample was very short, it might not be the answerer's fault.

Comment: If disabling AA isn't acceptable, leave a comment to the answer and wait for a different solution. (The edit to your question should really be a comment to the answer.)